# How to count if cell contains * in end of words in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have a scenario in A2= `Mahe12*`
Now I need to count the cell if cell ends with `*`

I tried `countif(A2,"*")` but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
=COUNT(INDEX(IF(LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C11,"\*$"))<>1,,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: **But of course you are correct** @JvdV . I already upvoted [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66331647/1527780). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to classify/tag this as a regular expression. `COUNTIF()` among other functions do support wildcards with the asterisk being one of them.

From the docs:

> "*A question mark matches any single character; an asterisk matches any sequence of characters. If you want to find an actual question mark or asterisk, type a tilde (~) before the character*"

Though poorly documented in the [`COUNTIF()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) section, the mechanics are the same as say; [`VLOOKUP()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en). Under "Notes" it shows that you can simply escape this special meaning using a tilde:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A,"*~*")
```

- `*` - Meaning 0+ characters.
- `~*` - A literal asterisk.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(SUM(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; "\*$")))
```